# How call stored procedure using nodeJS + typeORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

How can I call a stored procedure using nodeJS and typeORM, database mysql

I have no idea how to do this

Comment: This link will help you https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-nodejs/call-stored-procedures/